# WordPress Page Slug with URL custom template

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to create a custom template file for my user profile page something like this URL http://localhost/wordpress/user/username.

Here you can see I have created a new page in Admin with this permalink `user` and I have created a new file in my theme directory at `theme/user/page-{slug}.php`  and below is my code for this file.

```
<?php 

/*
    Template Name: User Profile
*/
wp_head();

?>

This is user profile page
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I have also selected this template file in admin for this page and below is the screenshot of this newly created page.

[image]

But when I go to browser and try this URL http://localhost/wordpress/user/company , its giving me "Page Not Found" error.

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here ? How can I set a template based on this slug `company` here which has `user` in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out a solution. Below is how I have achieved this.

In my `functions.php` file, I have put below code.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_user_var', 0, 1);
function add_user_var($vars){
    $vars[] = 'user';
    return $vars;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^user/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?pagename=user&user=$matches[1]','top');
```

This generally adds a rewrite rule if it finds `user` in the URL.

Now I have added a page template file name called as `page-user.php` and added below code to grab my query string.

```
$user = get_query_var('user');
echo $user;
```

I have created a page in backend admin with slug `user` and selected this template for this page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to check the hierarchy of wordpress files and how they work. I am not a pro, but for example doc says:

> page-{slug}.php – If the page slug is privacy, WordPress will look to
> use page-privacy.php.

link: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

(there is a very nice diagram in the above link)

Thus, WP looking for
http://localhost/wordpress/user/page-company.php

But, apart from the above, you need to create a **custom post type** call **user** either via plugin or via function php code in functions.php file of your theme

You could check this link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have any custom post type for this. This is just my company name and I want to grab that slug and based on it I will fetch the data of this particular user.

Comment: Currently if i go here http://localhost/wordpress/user , my `page-user.php` file getting called. But as soon as I try with slug `company-name` - localhost/wordpress/user/company-name - its showing 404 not found page. I just want to get query string `company-name` in this template file.

Comment: I dont have any custom post type .. its just a slug I want to get and show data.

Comment: there is no **user** slug in wordpress but author.. In order to have user you need to create one, by Custom Post Type. Inside CPT settings, there is an option "how to call your slug" let's say, in your case user and after that, you could add your posts like you want to (company etc).

Comment: `user` is just my page url. It can be anything like `profile/company-name`.

Comment: I even try with `page-user-{slug}.php` by changing the file name. But not luck.

Comment: So my basic question is.. I just want my slug to grab from URL and based on dynamic slug .. there will be only one page template file I want to call.

Comment: So for instance, If I have a page something like `localhost/wordpress/profile/asfas` my page template should be called something like `page-profile-{slug}.php`. But this is not working.

Comment: How can I just dynamically get my slug and not creating static pages for each slug.

Comment: You just said it in your own comments. You have page-user.php that's why WP found your custom page.. You need to create the static php files you are talking about. Otherwise, you could have one static page template and send the IDs of every user, make a query and display information of each one accordingly

Comment: Can we have a quick call in Google Meet Please ?

Comment: I can share my screen to you.

Comment: I would love to my friend and I am trying to help you out. But now I am in the office and can't talk. I would send you a text later on to check it if you do not find your answer yet.

Comment: You have a static page and need to GET dynamic data.. not the opposite one.. Otherwise, try the plugin I told you and check if this is what you are looking for. If not, I would try to reach you again

Comment: I am not understanding what I need to do in plugin dear hence I asked you,.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62846/using-custom-dynamic-slug-for-a-page

Comment: I want something like this.

Comment: ok, seems to be a good tutorial.. just be careful because **user** is a define value for WP Users and may have conflicts.. Try something else in order to check it first

Comment: I have found a solution .. I am posting my answer now.